# Scraping Names with Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rstudio, rvest

I am trying to scrape the names from the following webpage: http://www.infogo.gov.on.ca/infogo/#orgProfile/4151/en

This is the code I have used

```
library(rvest)
rod_phillips<-html('http://www.infogo.gov.on.ca/infogo/#orgProfile/4151/en')
Rod_phillips %>%
+ html_node("#employees .small") %>%
+ html_text()
```

But, when I type in this code, I just get

```
[1] NA.
```

Any advice?

Comment: If you look at the source of that page, you'll see that there are no names in there. The data is added via javascript after the page loads R. `rvest` does not run javascript code. If you want to run javascript code, you'll need to use a package like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rod_phillips <- jsonlite::fromJSON("http://www.infogo.gov.on.ca/infogo/v1/organizations/get?orgId=4151&_=1568919026581")
postions <- rod_phillips$positions
```

Short explanation:

I opened chrome, click `F12` key, and than network. Than I paste your url to url tab. After you click enter, you can track what's happening in the network. You are mostly interested in `XHR` part. There you can see the site is sending GET requests to the server with with `aplication/json` response.

This is a laic explanation (I don't know much about networks).

Comment: Could you explain to me how you identified that file?

Comment: I added short explanation.